# how to retrieve multiple values from single column using AND operator

Tags: sql

I want to `grab user_id` when there is a match found for two values in `meta_value` column. For example, if there exist a record for `"tagowner"` and another values is `"999"`  in `meta_value` column only.

I tried using `IN` operator as :-

```
SELECT * from wp_usermeta where meta_value IN ('tagowner',999);
```

but this is also displaying results for other group also. I just need results  only for `"tagowner"` and `"999"` .

Thanks

Comment: How can a field have 2 values? `tagowner` and `999`

Comment: DB table is not normalized @AndyGee - Not a good practice. Seems to be a growing trend.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question but you can query multiple table columns at once using the AND operator. SELECT * from wp_usermeta where meta_value = tagowner AND meta_value = 999;.  Also, I would highly recommend using word presses built in methods to retrieve this data. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Hard to tell what you mean, but maybe you intend `tagowner IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: can you show us the results of the query? What type is meta_value? BLOB? Then you should wrap 999 as '999' also

Comment: You need to clarify better. Noone seems to understands, including myself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need user_ids for where both rows are present, you may use [EXISTS](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php) or self join:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta t1
WHERE meta_value = 'tagowner'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_usermeta t2 
            WHERE t2.meta_value = '999' 
            AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id )
```

example: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/442d0/1)

Comment: Hey D.raev ,  thnksssssssss  a  lot, your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

meta_value are non numeric type.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   wp_usermeta 
WHERE  meta_value IN ( 'tagowner', '999' );
```

Comment: Yes Wordpress meta_value is longtext and needs quotes for search !!